# Pyspark define UDF for windows

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to partition a DataFrame into windows and then for every column and window use a custom function (udf) using Spark's Python interface. This doesn't seem to work

```
w = Window().partitionBy(["col"]).rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, sys.maxsize)

def median_polish(rows, cols, values):
    // shape values as matrix defined by rows/cols
    // compute median polish
    // cast matrix back to vector
    return values
med_pol_udf = func.udf(median_polish, DoubleType())

for x in df.columns:
   if x.startswith("some string"):
      df = df.withColumn(x, med_pol_udf("rows", "cols", x).over(w))
```

Is this possible to do at all? Or does one need to do this in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that will not be possible but an alternative solution i had in mind that you can first create a column using same window and that column hold the unique partition number then perform the ntile operation on that column you can have what you want median value of all the columns over that window.